# CImg does not find function draw_text

Tags: macos, cimg

I'm trying to use the CImg library, but I can't get it to work. I'm working on a mac in terminal and I wrote a hello world program

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
const unsigned char purple[] = { 255,0,255 };
CImg<unsigned char>(640,400,1,3,0).draw_text("Hello World",100,100,purple).di\
splay("My first CImg code");
return 0;
}
```

which requires the "draw_text" function of the library. I included the header and compiled like

```
g++ -o hello_word.exe hello_world.cpp -O2 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11 -I/opt/X11/include
```

The error I get is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::draw_text(const char [12], int, int, const unsigned char [3])’
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the reference doc for the signatures of the functions `CImg<T>::draw_text()` :

http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a8ff42ad9cc3368b2d70621c23d36cf17

And now, try this :

```
CImg<unsigned char>(640,400,1,3,0).draw_text(100,100,"Hello World",purple).display("My first CImg code");
```

Also look at all examples provided in the CImg Library package (folder `examples/`), there are a lot of things to learn from them.